# List of all products with user's saved products

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having an issue trying to figure out a query that will allow me to show a list of all of my product as well as showing whether or not a user has saved any given product.

I have 3 tables involved in the query (users, product_user, product).
I am determing whether or not a user has saved a product by joining the three tables and checking if user_id is null or not with the following query:

```
SELECT products.*, users.id as 'user_id' FROM products
       LEFT JOIN product_user ON  products.id = product_user.product_id
       LEFT JOIN users ON product_user.user_id = users.id AND users.id =1;
```

However this returns duplicate rows when the user has saved a product (user_id null version and user_id = 1 version). A distinct statement won't work because the rows aren't distinct in this case. What is best practices to ensure that I only get back distinct products? I need to get back the entire list of products, whether or not the user has saved it.

This is being queried in mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select p.*,
       (select pu.user_id
        from product_user pu
        where pu.product_id = p.id and pu.user_id = 1
        limit 1
       ) as user_id
from products p;
```

This will return only one row per `product`.  The row will have the `user_id` -- only once and it has to match whatever you pass in.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!